# Возможно ли добавить тег html на страницу в браузере?

Tags: python, python-3.x, html5

К примеру я создал html страницу sait.com

Возможно ли средствами Python внести локальные изменения на этот сайт? А именно вставить тег с подключением нового css файла или любой другой тег

То есть, при запуске программы видоизменяется (локально) цветовая палитра сайта(через вставку нового тега в html)

Comment: не очень хорошо понял Ваш вопрос, но если все таки понял, то ответом будет да, возможно)

Comment: Пишите скрипт, который редактирует нужный вам файл нужным вам образом, да и всё

Answer (score 0):

HTML это обычный файл, структура которого – символы.

Следовательно вы можете просто открыть этот файл с помощью Python, отредактировать нужную строку(и) и сохранить обратно.

Если вы хотите разным пользователям давать разные виды сайтов возможно такой вариант подойдет. Он очень похож то, как работает PHP. При каждом запросе PHP генерирует страницу и отправляет пользователю. Тоже самое вы можете сделать и с Python. Попробовать можете например с помощью библиотеки Flask. [Пример](https://realpython.com/primer-on-jinja-templating/) как это работает.

Более важный вопрос, зачем вам делать это через Python? После перезаписи файла, браузеру придется перезагрузить его. Если вам требуется изменять стили сайта в зависимости от определенных условий во время его работы используйте JavaScript.